# The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for getRange()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a script to fetch data from Google Analytics. I wrote this using help from lots of sites and youtube videos but unable to fix 1 issue in my code.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var app = SpreadsheetApp
      var doc = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      for(var i=0;i<107;i++){ 
      var viewId = doc.getRange(i+2,1).getValue(); // Your Google Analytics view ID

      var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(doc.getRange("K1").getValue(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(doc.getRange("K2").getValue(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd");;
      var metric = 'ga:sessions, ga:newUsers, ga:bounceRate';
      var option = {'segment': 'gaid::reM9CWAgR0ys4_Ng4N_aVw'};

        var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(viewId, startDate, endDate, metric, option); // Make the request

        var sessions = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions'];
        var newusers = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:newUsers'];
        var bouncerate = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:bounceRate'];

        var doc = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Current document
        var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet(); // Current sheet

        sheet.getRange(i+2,2,1,1).setValue(sessions); // Write total sessions
        sheet.getRange(i+2,3,1,1).setValue(newusers); // Write toal newusers
        sheet.getRange(i+2,4,1,1).setValue(bouncerate); // Write total bouncerate
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please do not just put the entire content of your question in the title..Instead, [edit] your post to provide more details, including the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Please provide the full message error including the line where the error is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This Got auto resolved once I changed the View ID in my sheet. I guess the problem was with view ID

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the script does not find the startDate or endDate in K1 and/or K2 cell or because there are less then 107 view ids and by looping it finds an empty cell in the first column (or do not start from the second cell).

It doesn't depend on Google Analytics.