# Data Discrepancy in Google Analytics & API Results in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I have created this script to fetch data from Google Analytics. I have used the same segment(organic Traffic) and metrics that i need. But there is a small difference in Numbers. For most it wont matter but for me i always want accuracy. I am not able to figure out the reason for this difference in Analytics & API Results

```js
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var doc = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var value = doc.getRange('E:E').getValues()
  for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){ 
  var viewId = app.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2,5).getValue(); // Your Google Analytics view ID
 
  var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(doc.getRange("O1").getValue(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(doc.getRange("O2").getValue(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    
  var metric = 'ga:sessions, ga:newUsers, ga:bounceRate';
    
  var option = {'segment': 'gaid::-5'};
    
    var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(viewId, startDate, endDate, metric, option);
    
 var sessions = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions'];
    var newusers = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:newUsers'];
    var bouncerate = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:bounceRate'];
  
    var doc = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Current document
    var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet(); // Current sheet
  
    sheet.getRange(i+2,6,1,1).setValue(sessions); // Write total sessions
    sheet.getRange(i+2,7,1,1).setValue(newusers); // Write toal newusers
    sheet.getRange(i+2,8,1,1).setValue(bouncerate); // Write total bouncerate
}
  
}
```

The result i get after running this code is :
[Google Spreadsheet Script Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pF1F.png)
And the result i get in Google Analytics for the exact same date range is -

[Google Analytics Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOP2D.png)

I checked the Sampling level, its 100% in Analytics. which u can see in screenshot

Comment: Did you solved that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416457/the-parameters-string-number-dont-match-the-method-signature-for-spreadsheeta if yes, mark it as resolved please

Comment: Can Someone Help with this please? I have similar discrepancy in Search Console Data as well. The Data shown on search console website differs from the result of my API Script. Does Anyone know why this could have happened?

I have checked the possibility of Data Sampling and that is not the reason for this mismatch